# Calling php script from java - Android

Tags: java, php, android, http

I have the following copyfile.php file inside my main directory with the below code :

```
<?php
copy("dir1/test.php","dir2/test.php");
?>
```

Basically just moving a file from dir1 to dir2 (both the directories are already created and are present in my main directory)

I am using the following java code to call my copyfile.php

```
try {
        URL url;
        url = new URL( "http://www.xyz.com/copyfile.php" );
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if( conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK ){
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                        // do something with the data here
        }else{
                        InputStream err = conn.getErrorStream();
                        // err may have useful information.. but could be null see javadocs for more information
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

The program runs without any errors but the file is not being copied.

But if I paste the above url (http://www.xyz.com/copyfile.php) in the browser it works fine the file gets copied to dir2. Am I doing something wrong? Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: are you sure there are no errors. Where are you calling this whole try{...}catch[ } thing? Have a look at the `LogCat` too. Also try to make a `Log.i("HTTP call", "Worked")` and the same with "error" in your if else statement

Comment: check the url by rest client browser extensions, if it works then there is some problem with the request you have created

Comment: i was missing the .execute call of my AsyncTask its working now. Thanks for ur time  and help :)